# I am trying to print a table with a double method..yet not working

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

i can't seem to make the table that i am trying to print stop at 60.000 as it was suposed to. 
the  printing goes on forever witch makes me  belive i have created an infinite  for loop..
the ideia is to print a table that gives the tax for values bettewn 50000 and 60000 in 4 types of fillers and with increment of 50 for every new row...

```
public class FinantialAplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int status=0;
        double taxableIncome=0;         

        System.out.printf("Taxable Income\tSingle\tMarried Filling Jointly\tMarried Filling Sepratly\tHead Of Household\n");
        System.out.printf("                           or Qualifing Widower\n");
        System.out.print("______________________________________________________________________________________________________\n");

        printTable(status,taxableIncome);
    }

    public static double printTable(int status, double taxableIncome){
        double tax1,tax2,tax3,tax4;
        for ( taxableIncome=50000;taxableIncome<60000;taxableIncome =taxableIncome+50){         
            tax1 = 8350*0.10+(33950-8350)*0.15+(taxableIncome-33950);
            tax2 = 16700*0.10+(taxableIncome-16700)*0.15;
            tax3 = 8350*0.10+(33950-8350)*0.15+(taxableIncome-33950);
            tax4 = 11950*0.10+(45500-11950)*015+(taxableIncome-45500);

            if (taxableIncome>=50000 && taxableIncome<=60000){
                System.out.println(Math.round(taxableIncome)+"  "+Math.round(tax1)+"  "+Math.round(tax2)+"  "+Math.round(tax3)+"  "+Math.round(tax4));
            }
        }
        return printTable(status,taxableIncome);
    }

}
```

any help will be most welcome.

thank you in advance...

Comment: You pass `taxableIncome` as a parameter but then set it to `50000`. So it does the `for` loop then calls itself, each time resetting `taxableIncome` to `50000` and thus never ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you print forever is because you don't have an exit check. You have a recursive function that doesn't give yourself a way out. To exit at 60 you could do:

```
  public static void printTable(int status, double taxableIncome){
        double tax1,tax2,tax3,tax4;
        for ( taxableIncome=50000;taxableIncome<60000;taxableIncome =taxableIncome+50){         
            tax1 = 8350*0.10+(33950-8350)*0.15+(taxableIncome-33950);
            tax2 = 16700*0.10+(taxableIncome-16700)*0.15;
            tax3 = 8350*0.10+(33950-8350)*0.15+(taxableIncome-33950);
            tax4 = 11950*0.10+(45500-11950)*015+(taxableIncome-45500);

            if (taxableIncome>=50000 && taxableIncome<=60000){
                System.out.println(Math.round(taxableIncome)+"  "+Math.round(tax1)+"  "+Math.round(tax2)+"  "+Math.round(tax3)+"  "+Math.round(tax4));
            }
        }

    }
```

You change the return type from `double` to `void` because you don't need to return anything. By returning the function, you will continue to run until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method signature of printTable to:

```
public static void printTable(int status)
```

Remove the return statement and alter the for loop to:

```
for (double taxableIncome = 50000; taxableIncome < 60000; taxableIncome += 50)
```

The problem is the return statement in the printTable method - each time it's reached, the same method is called recursively again, at which point a new local taxableIncome variable is created with a value of 50000 and hence the printing continues indefinitely.

Comment: I added a change to the FOR loop declaration as per Moob's comment that passing taxableIncome into the method is redundant. Not essential to make it work, but neater.